# OnChange or OnBlur event in javascript to run python function in Django and return the results?

Tags: python, django, onchange, onblur

I have developed an internal tool with Django and Python in the backend, now it seems like I have hit a road block.

I am very new to Javascript. And the site has to be very dynamic and it needs to be able to do something like the following:

In the input box,

1. The user has entered data
2. When the user moves out from the box, it runs an onBlur or onChange or some event function which calls a python code that takes some arguments, and takes other data from the page and Inserts that data in the database and saves.
3. It does that with out changing the url/refreshing the page or anything just staying on the same page.

Any ideas how to accomplish this with Python and Django.

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Murtaza Pitalwala

Comment: You would have to use ajax to send post request when onblur/onchange event happens. You will find lot of information about how to use ajax to do that.

Answer (score 2):

#### Javascript as you describe

```
$("#foo").change(function() { 
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/some_url/',
      data: {
          'some_data_from_page': $("#some_data_from_page").val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
          alert("Got response from server ...", data);
      }
    });
});
```

#### Some generic html

```
<input type="text" id="foo" />
<input type="text" id="some_data_from_page" />
```

#### Some generic django

```
def handle_ajax_post(request):
    print 'Doing something with post data... perhaps saving to the database?', \
            request.POST['some_data_from_page']

    return http.HttpRespones("Some response from server")
```

Comment: Thanks very much Yuji. I should have mentioned javascript or jquery would work both. I will test it with this code and will let you know if I have any other questions.

Comment: Hello Yuji, 

@YujiTomita

I would like to show you the error I am getting and what I am doing but it seems like I dont have a lot of space to show you everything and its coming out all mushed in together.. really hard to ready... 

Is it possible to email you what I have and then maybe you can guide me through?

Comment: Sure, I'm sure you can find my email

Comment: Found your email and sent you what I am doing.. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks, Murtaza..

Comment: How to do it using angular ?

Comment: I think you guys should share how you solved a problem instead of emails